# How to simulate requests per minute in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to simulate 'n' number of request per minute.  I am load testing 5 different webservices each of which should be simulated with different 'n' requests per minute.  Which is the best way?. Do I have to use timers?.  Can I attach a timer to a Sampler or should it be attached to a thread group only?.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Add a [Constant Throughput Timer][1] to the Thread Group.

If you want a separate value of req per minute for each web service, you can create 5 thread groups with 5 timers.
Run all of them in one Test Plan

Comment: trust JoseK, he knows the way.

Comment: @BlackGaff: he he I beat you to this one ;)

Comment: Curses! * shakes fist * You will rue the day ;)