# configure number of concurrent requests in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter to replay our Apache log file(Using Access Log Sampler), to get some performance data.

The replay of the log works fine, but the problem is that jmeter is only using 1 thread to send all requests, so it fires one request, and then it waits for the response before it sends the next request.

I would really like the ability to specify the number of concurrent requests so I could for example say that there should always be 10 requests in flight, but it does not looks like any of the thread groups allows this with the newest version. So is there a way to do this in Jmeter, og is that impossible?

The closest I came was was that I can specify "Number of threads (Users)" as 10. This does cause jmeter to have 10 threads in flight, but the problem is that it all these threads will request the same url. I need all the threads to request different urls.

I am using the newest jmeter (5.6.2).

Comment: Parameterize the test URL as described [here](https://medium.com/@LabAssurance/how-to-read-data-from-csv-file-in-jmeter-parameterization-5b73c0a15c98). Number of threads is a different concern that has nothing to do with the test data, and there are several questions about that, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5018846/839733) one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Access Log Sampler supports the scenario you described.

You should rather consider parsing the access log somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), extract URLs from there and save them into a CSV file. Then use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) in the "normal" Thread Group to feed the URLs into HTTP Request sampler, with default "Sharing Mode" of `All threads` it will read next URL from the CSV file on each iteration of each virtual user.