# How to fire 10 requests per second in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

How to fire 10 requests per second instead of waiting for previous threads to complete in jmeter.

Need to hit 1000 times,

Currently the below configuration in Thread Group,
Number of users : 10
Loop :100

I guess the thread is waiting to get response even after second.

But I need to fire 10 requests per second irrespective of response.

Constant Throughput Timer will be useful to do this ?
if that is the case what configuration I should provide .

Any help is highly appreciated..

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232700/how-to-simulate-requests-per-minute-in-jmeter

Answer (score 10):

Yes, Constant Throughput Timer will definitely help.

1. Put `600` in Target Throughput field (10 requests/second * 60 seconds)
2. Change "Calculate Throughput based on" to be `All active threads`
3. Make sure that you have enough threads. Personally I would increase it at least to 20 as JMeter is not capable of kicking off extra threads to generate the requested throughput, it can only pause threads to limit the load to defined value
4. Make sure that your tests lasts long enough. Constant Throughput Timer is quite accurate on "minute" level so your test needs to last for at least 1 minute. Also consider reasonable ramp-up and ramp-down values to avoid "spikes"

See [How to use JMeter's Throughput Constant Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) guide for more detailed explanations and instructions.

By the way, there is an enhanced version called [Throughput Shaping Timer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) available at [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) bundle, maybe it'll be easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 
Stepping Thread Group.
It will help you to specify time and number of thread to be fired in that time interval.

https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3TEw.png)