# JMeter number of threads in a run

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am quite new to jmeter and try to do a performance test of my application. I want to generate 100 request per second scenario however my server takes 3-4 secs to respond to every request. I am running my test for 1 mins which means number of requests fired should be 60k within the time span. However jmeter actually waits for the response before it sends next request. Which is not what I am looking for.

How can I make sure that jmeter sends a new requests every second with 100 req/sec without waiting for the response so that the number of requests fired per min is 60k.

I am trying to use constant throughput timer with 60k as request per min, however that is not helping. Here is my test screenshot.

[image: Jmeter test]

**EDIT**

I have done like this
[image: Concurrency Thread group]

And Throughput shaping timer being as
[image: Throughput shaping timer]

So ideally I should get number of samples as 3000?, still not getting that.

Comment: There's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30389238/how-to-fire-10-requests-per-second-in-jmeter?rq=1

Comment: gone through that question however the summary report shows number of samples being 250 only in 50 seconds...while it should be 2500 samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you provide enough threads (virtual users) under [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group), "vanilla" JMeter won't kick off any extra threads if actual throughput is less than target one you specify in the Constant Throughput Timer.

Another solution would be using [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) along with the [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/). They can be tied together via [feedback loop](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Schedule-Feedback-Function) so if you use these test elements JMeter will start more threads if the current amount won't be enough to reach the desired requests per second rate.

You can install both using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: Hey Dmitri, I have done as suggested, please see the edit...I should be seeing number of samples as 3000 now in 1 min, however its not like that. can you please advise if I am doing something wrong. My server responds in 10 -11 second for a thread..so 50*10 = 500 threads should be able to cater that, I have kept upper limit as 2000 however. Not able to follow how this is working.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to consider using the Arrivals Thread Group. This TG will allow you to configure the desire average throughput (ATP); the TG will instantiate the required threads needed to achieve the ATP goal.